# Adicionar registros a una tabla de postgres desde un archivo csv

Tags: postgresql, csv

Agradeceré su gran apoyo para adicionar registros a una tabla de postgresql, explorando en el sitio https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/ encontré lo siguiente ejemplo:

```sql
COPY persons(first_name, last_name, dob, email)
FROM 'C:\sampledb\persons.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Sin embargo, agradeceré su confirmación en reafirmarme si los datos existente se pierden o el resultado es un adición de registros?, lo que requiero es la ADICIÓN.

Respetos para Ustedes.

Answer (score 1):

Siempre la primer opción que debes de buscar es la documentación oficial. En este caso [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Según la documentación:

> COPY FROM copia datos de un archivo a una tabla (añadiendo los datos a
> lo que ya esté en la tabla)

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente la documentación es clara.